# Accessing nested iframes with selenium in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I'm currently working on running a scrape from a website that requires a bit of navigation. After logging into the site, I need to populate a search bar to return various values as I work through the scrape.

The search bar is in a total of four nested iframes, and for whatever reason I can't access it. I'm able to get into the first iframe, but when I try to get to the next iframe, I get a NoSuchElement error. I've confirmed that my code is actually switching to the iframe, but it can't access any elements within the frame.

Here's a screenshot of the code I'm working in. I've highlighted each of the iframes in yellow and the search bar element in blue: [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLeO0.png)

Here is the code I currently have to reference the iframes.

```
Sub UserData()
    Dim text As Boolean
    Dim ele As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim drv As Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim user As String
    Dim pass As String
    
    Set drv = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    user = "user"
    pass = "password"

    drv.Get "https://mc.login.exacttarget.com/hub-cas/login?service=https%3a%2f%2fmc.s7.exacttarget.com%2fcloud%2flogin.html%3fhash%3dOrEn1bG9nZ2VkLWluSXc9PQ2"

    drv.FindElementById ("username")
    drv.SendKeys user
    Set objcollection = drv.FindElementById("submit-btn")
    objcollection.Click

    drv.FindElementById ("password")
    drv.SendKeys pass
    Set objcollection = drv.FindElementById("submit-btn")
    objcollection.Click

    drv.Wait (10)

    drv.Get "https://mc.s7.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Email/C12/Default.aspx?entityType=none&entityID=0%23Content"

    drv.Wait (10)

    drv.SwitchToFrame drv.FindElementByClass("mc-app-iframe")
    
    drv.SwitchToFrame drv.FindElementById("fraContent")

End Sub
```

I've also tried referencing the next iframe with XPath, Class, and Name, all with the same error. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: So, to clarify, this `drv.SwitchToFrame drv.FindElementById("fraContent")` gets you into the second iframe but you can't then find any child elements? And is this the same if you .Get to the src of that iframe? (Adding the protocol/domain if required)

Comment: @QHarr I'm actually only able to get into the first `iframe drv.SwitchToFrame drv.FindElementByClass("mc-app-iframe")`, and it doesn't look like the program finds any child elements. I ran a line to get the tag of the current element after it switches to the "mc-app-iframe" iframe and it returns "body".  I haven't tried getting to the src of the iframe. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Were you able to find just the element `drv.FindElementById("fraContent")` ; also, can you retrieve any additional iframe tag elements?

Comment: @QHarr I haven't been able to find the "fraContent" iframe, and I can't retrieve any other elements onec I've selected the "mc-app-iframe" iframe.

Upon further inspection, I can find one div element with the id "root" inside the frame.

Comment: @QHarr I figured it out. Apparently there are multiple iframes on this page under the class "mc-app-iframe", so the program was targeting the incorrect iframe. I changed the attribute reference and was able to switch to the correct iframe as well as locate all the nested iframes to access my target element. Thanks!